# Projective modules over semilocal rings having constant rank are free

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, algebraic-k-theory

I'm starting to study algebraic K-theory by myself and I need a hint how to prove

> $R$ is a semilocal ring with maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_1,\ldots, \mathfrak m_n$, $P$ is a projective module and there exists $k$ such that
>   $$P_{\mathfrak m_i}\cong (R_{\mathfrak m_i})^k$$
>   for all $i=1,\dots,n$, then $P$ is a free module.

If I prove that $P$ is a stably free module, we're done, because $R$ is a semilocal ring.

Since $P$ is projective, the $P_{\mathfrak m_i}$ are free for every $i$.

I need help how to continue, I'm a really beginner in this subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user121097 but $P$ is not necessarily finitely generated.